# Device tilting degrees on Android

Tags: android, android-sensors

I'm working on a video game where the tilt is the primary control method for the players.
But I would like the players to be able to play the game even lying on a couch.
Currently the game works best if the device is flat, and still works if you tilt a little bit because I calculate the starting point of the accelerometer. But this gives unexpected results.

Is there a way in Android to calculate the device's rotation (degrees) from a specific starting point? Is it even possible at all? Was anyone able to accomplish this?
I know that SpeedX were able to master rotation, but I need it for tilting.

Thank you

Comment: Can do something like , when youre starting a game, let the user notify, that youll calibrate their device and then get the current tilt of the device and store it into startingTilt. Then, whenever youre getting the tilt of their device, just do (currentTilt-startingTilt). Basically , at the start of the game, get their tilt and manage later input relative to that starting tilt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get constant callbacks about angular (rotational) velocity. It is up to you to convert that to an angular position. [1]

[1] http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-gyro

Comment: Thank you, the document is a bit hard to understand but I found this great example that helps:

https://bitbucket.org/apacha/sensor-fusion-demo/

Answer (score 1):

You can get the device rotation degrees through

```
OrientationEventListener.onOrientationChanged()
```

which ranges from 0 to 359 degree, though you'll have to calculate the difference between the starting point and the changes in rotational degrees yourself.

```
void onOrientationChanged (int orientation) { 
    //orientation is an argument which represents rotation in degrees
}
```

also you can enable and disable this listener by calling `enable()` and `disable()` methods of the listener. Here are the [deveoper reference docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html) from google.

[this](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/08/orientationeventlistener-detect.html) is a link on to how use orientation listener.

```
public class SimpleOrientationActivity extends Activity {
  OrientationEventListener mOrientationListener;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      mOrientationListener = new OrientationEventListener(this,
          SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) {

          @Override
          public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
            Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Orientation changed to " + orientation);

          }
      };

     if (mOrientationListener.canDetectOrientation() == true) {
         Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Can detect orientation");
         mOrientationListener.enable();
     } else {
         Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Cannot detect orientation");
         mOrientationListener.disable();
     }

  }

  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      mOrientationListener.disable();
  }
}
```

There are other rate values appropriate for game use and other purposes. The default rate, SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, is most appropriate for simple orientation changes. Other values, such as SENSOR_DELAY_UI and SENSOR_DELAY_GAME might work for you.

[This](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2262133&seqNum=4) is another useful link that implements the same code and provides good explanation.

Comment: do we need permission for using this sensor @Akash?

Comment: No permission is required - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener